# Switch DAX rebate based on cumulative measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I am having a bit of tough time wrapping my head around this. I have a cumulative total based on hours and I need to calculate the rebate. The rule here is that after that total exceeds an amount, change the rebate percentage (10%, 15%). Regardless how I try it, I end up with the wrong total or the wrong percentage.

Here's my failed approach:

```
+------------+-------------+------------+
| Day        | BilledHours | LaborPrice |
+------------+-------------+------------+
| 07/01/2018 | 98          | 13000      |
+------------+-------------+------------+
| 07/02/2018 | 89          | 12000      |
+------------+-------------+------------+
| 07/03/2018 | 80          | 11000      |
+------------+-------------+------------+
| 07/04/2018 | 92          | 9000       |
+------------+-------------+------------+
| 07/05/2018 | 52          | 8000       |
+------------+-------------+------------+
| 07/06/2018 | 73          | 7000       |
+------------+-------------+------------+
| 07/07/2018 | 82          | 11000      |
+------------+-------------+------------+


Cumulative Hours = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Rebates[BilledHours]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(Rebates[Day]),
        Rebates[Day]<=MAX(Rebates[Day]))
        )

Rebate = 
SUMX(Rebates,
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        [Cumulative Hours]<=400,Rebates[LaborPrice] * 0.10,
        [Cumulative Hours]>=401,Rebates[LaborPrice] * 0.15)
        )
```

[image]

How can I achieve the correct rebate and total? If I use the SWITCH before the sum, I end up with the incorrect total (since the total is always > 400).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, modify your measure for Cumulative Hours as follows:

```
Cumulative Hours =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Rebates[BilledHours] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( Rebates ), Rebates[Day] <= MAX ( Rebates[Day] ) )
)
```

Second, modify Rebate measure:

```
Rebate =
SUMX (
    Rebates,
    VAR Cumulative_Hours = [Cumulative Hours]
    RETURN
        SWITCH (
            TRUE (),
            Cumulative_Hours <= 400, Rebates[LaborPrice] * 0.1,
            Cumulative_Hours >= 401, Rebates[LaborPrice] * 0.15
        )
)
```

Result:
[image]

**Why your formula is not working:**

Create a simple test measure and visualize it:

```
   Wrong Rebate Hours = SUMX( Rebates, [Cumulative Hours])
```

[image]

It's easy to see that there is no "accumulation" -  [Cumulative Hours] inside SUMX stop being cumulative, and as a result your SWITCH test is always < 400. Essentially, SUMX modifies filter context of the [Cumulative Hours] measure by introducing row context from Rebates (through "context transition" - lookup the concept on Google).

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation @RADO. I get why it does not work but still cannot figure out how to get around it. I tried your approach as a measure but it got an error message ("A single values for column 'Labor Price' in table 'Rebates' cannot be determined...) If I do it as a calculate column instead, I get a totally wrong result. I chose SWITCH because there are other conditions that I have to add for different categories (e.g. if the cumulative hours in the past quarter are < x). Can you please update your answer to show me how you would write the VAR? Thanks again.

Comment: @iCosmin - sorry it was my bad; in my formula, I used a measure for Labor Hours, but forgot to explain that. Anyway, I simplified the solution for you and used SWITCH with a variable. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: The solution is really elegant. Runs like butter! Thank you for your time @RADO!